# Work with returned array from function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return an array from a function and work with its results.

When I just want to get its length, I always get a 0:

```
function myFunc() {
  var arr = [];

  arr.push("test");
  arr.push("another test");

  return arr;
}

alert(myFunc.length) // expected 2, but got 0
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x91a7xsx/1/).

Comment: `alert(myFunc().length) `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call it as `myfunc().length` because you are calling a function.

Answer (score 3):

Remember you are calling a function, so the parameter list (even if empty) must be given to the call, try:

```
alert(myFunc().length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function like so

```
function myFunc() {
  var arr = [];

  arr.push("test");
  arr.push("another test");

  return arr;
}

alert(myFunc().length)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n5xdcrzm/

Answer (score 0):

> [**`Function.length`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), The length property specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.

And that is the reason you could get `0` in alert as you are reading `length` property of the `function-object`

If you are expecting `2`, which is length of the `array`, you need to invoke the `function`.

`function myFunc` returns the `array` in which `2` items are being `pushed`.

Invoke the function and read the `length` property of the returned `array`

```js
function myFunc() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push("test");
  arr.push("another test");
  return arr;
}

alert(myFunc().length);
```